# While and for loops with math, lists, even, odd, squares

Tags: python

So I got the following code in Python 3, but the second part which is the sum of squares between 1 and 100 isn't quite working and need help trying to figure it out.
Also please if it can be simplified or changed just a bit like not using the def function because i really dont know how to use it well and just make it easier but getting the same exact results for the program I have to submit it on it'd be great (it's very picky)
Thanks

```
a=2
b=101
c=2
first=[]
second=[]
third=[]
fourth=[]
for numseven in range (a,b,c):
    first.append(numseven)
print(sum(first))
print(2+2**2+3**2+4**2+6**2+7**2+8**2+9**2+10**2)
print("1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768 65536 131072 262144 524288 1048576")
for squarenums in range (1,101):
      second.append(squarenums)
def escuer(second):
      return [i ** 2 for i in second]
print(sum(escuer(second)))
print(escuer(second))
d=int(input("Type a number "))
e=int(input("And  another one "))
f=d-1
for odd in range(f,e,c):
    third.append(odd)
print(sum(third))
word=input("The numbers are *drums* ")
for wordisodd in range(len(word)):
    fourth.append(wordisodd)
    print(fourth)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post the expected result compared to the actual result you are getting?

Comment: Hey! Yes I'm getting 361 for the sum of squares and it's supposed to be 385 I believe, I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing 5^2 and you have 2 instead of 1^2

Try:

```
print(1**2+2**2+3**2+4**2+5**2+6**2+7**2+8**2+9**2+10**2)
```

Try this for something a little easier to follow:

```
def square(x):
    return x**2

numbers = list(range(1,11)) # this gives a list from 1-10

square_numbers = [square(x) for x in numbers]

sum_squares = sum(square_numbers)

print(sum_squares)
```

You can even merge the above four lines into:

```
print(sum([square(x) for x in list(range(1,11))]))
```

Comment: No problem. Feel free to hit the checkmark to validate the answer :)

Comment: It went through perfectly! Any suggestions on simplifying it without going into advanced stuff? Just to make future work easier